# Docker compose doesn't recognize 'env_file'

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-build

I am trying to run `docker-compose up` with the following configuration:

```yaml
php:
    image: php:7.0-fpm
    expose:
        - 9000
    links:
        - nginx

nginx:
    env_file: .env
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 433:433
    environment:
        - NGINX_HOST: ${APP_URL}

mysql:
    env_file: .env
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
        - MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: no
```

I have an `.env` file in the same directory and am able to test the variable in the shell, but docker doesn't seem to load the `.env`.

> **WARNING**: The APP_URL variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
>
> **WARNING**: The DB_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
>
> **WARNING**: The DB_DATABASE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
>
> **WARNING**: The DB_USERNAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
>
> **ERROR**: Validation failed in file './docker-compose.yaml'

**UPDATE**

I just changed the `env_file` value to point to a non-existing file and no errors are thrown. It seems like docker is completely ignoring the option.

Comment: You can always check if the docker-compose file is set up as you expected with: `docker-compose convert` Then you're able to see the actual settings (no need to trial and error).

Comment: I have the same issue using the same configuration file (except I'm using MariaDB instead of MySQL). It seems like PHP & MySQL are receiving the environment correctly whereas NGINX is not. I have to manually provide the environment variable to the `nginx` service by using the `environment` key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like many other version related issues, updating to *v1.7.1* of **docker-compose** resolved the issue, works like a charm!

Comment: How do you update docker-compose? I have the latest version of Docker 17.06.0 and docker-compose is 1.14.1

Comment: I also have compose in 1.14.0 and docker in 17.05 but can't get environment variables work in docker-compose file.

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue because I wasn't running `$docker-compose up` from the same directory as my `.env` and `docker-compose.yml` file. The command can still find the `docker-compose.yml` file, through a search, but it doesn't also search that location for the `.env` file.