# env_file is ignored in docker-compose and cause "The ... variable is not set" warning

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

I simply want to use a environment variable loaded from file in my docker-compose file. But after running the container, I only got

> WARNING: The TESTVAR variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.

Only found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982317/docker-compose-doesnt-recognize-env-file), but I'm using a later version of docker like there (docker-compose: `1.14.0`, docker: `17.05.0-ce`). And I changed the encoding to `ISO 8859-1`, since I found a github issue where strange behavior with encodings was detected. Both doesn't work.

My docker-compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: test_${TESTVAR}
    build: mysql
    mem_limit: 1G
    env_file:
      - credentials.env
```

credentials.env contains only `TESTVAR=test123`. To start, I run `docker-compose up mysql` and I also tried to specify the environment variables directly in the compose file like this:

```
environment:
  - TESTVAR=1234
```

Not working, too.

Comment: Not sure what you are actually trying to achieve. Env variables will be available INSIDE the container by the container itself, not while running a docker-compose file. If you want that to work you have to export TESTVAR in your environment.

Comment: Please look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495663/docker-compose-env-file-not-working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variables in the docker-compose.yml you can do it with .env file, [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

```
$ cat .env
TAG=v1.5
TESTVAR=123

$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: "webapp:${TAG}"
    environment: ["TESTVAR=${TESTVAR}"]
```

Comment: you can have files common.env, prod.env, prod.private.env... but when deploying to production you will just copy the proper file to destination with name .env ... so the docker-compose.yml will always expect .env file but it is up to you to copy the proper file based on your ENV